# how to add ZURB CSS Grid Builder to Foundation 4

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation, builder

I've downloaded the latest version of Foundation 4.3.2 CSS version and I try to add/display the Grid using ZURB CSS Grid Builder (available at http://zurb.com/playground/css-grid-builder).

I want the grid to be displayed over the actual layout - something  like !
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hu4K.png

I've created a file called grid.css in css folder and add the content of ZURB CSS Grid Builder.

I've added the css in the index.html file in :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" />
```

but the grid is not displayed (actually the layout is broken).

**How can I add ZURB Grid to Foundation 4 ?**

Answer (score 0):

The Grid Builder is a tool to generate code for a standalone CSS grid that you can use to structure a site, not to overlay a literal grid on top of the existing layout.

Additionally Foundation 4 already has a grid built into it.  The grid builder is just to generate grid CSS for people who want to use a customized version of Foundation's grid without using the rest of Foundation.

Refer to [F4's documentation for the grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html).  If you want a grid "overlay" you want something completely different, and it will probably be easier to add a transparent graphic of the grid or something over top of the layout rather than trying to add a whole grid overlay in CSS.  There are also plenty of Firefox and Chrome extensions which will allow you to overlay a custom grid on pages in your browser.